# How to convert .doc / .xls file into PDF using Java

Tags: java

I want to convert .doc/.xls file into PDF through my java application. Now, I know there have been some discussions on this topic. I also know that JODConverter is one option, but the problem with this is dependency on OpenOffice. Whoever wants to use my app will first need to install OpenOffice on his/her host. I want to avoid this. Do we have any new solution through which I can do this conversion in my app without having dependencies on any other applications.

Answer (score 0):

You could use POI for reading XLS and DOC, and use iText for generating the PDF.

POI project:
http://jakarta.apache.org/poi/

iText project:
http://www.lowagie.com/iText